# Httpclient alternative

Tags: android, httpclient

I'm building an app to connect with nodemcu. In my code I am using `HttpClient`, but as I have read that it is no longer supported. I want to use `httpurlConnection` in the below code. I am getting errors if use `httpurlconnection`. Here is the code

```
if (!dialog.isShowing())
        dialog.show();

        String val = params[0];
        final String url = "http://" + serverAdress + "/led/" + val;

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet();
            getRequest.setURI(new URI(url));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

            InputStream inputStream = null;
            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader =
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            serverResponse = bufferedReader.readLine();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            serverResponse = e.getMessage();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            serverResponse = e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            serverResponse = e.getMessage();
        }

        return serverResponse;
}
```

Comment: `HttpUrlConnection` Please show adapted code in another code block.

Comment: why dont you try retrofit if its a simple GET request

Comment: @greenapps what code

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you take a look at [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) Library. Actually, latest versions of HttpsURLConnection using OkHttp under the hood. Or higher level Library [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), which using OkHttp but its APIs simpler to use. Also if your server is RESTful you can use Adapters/Converters to simply deserialize responses to Java objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HttpsURLConnection request = (HttpsURLConnection) (url.openConnection());
request.setRequestMethod("GET");
request.connect();
String result = readStream(request.getInputStream());
request.disconnect();
```